# How to execute code on page that is not reloading

Tags: javascript, url

On a page eg .../something/jonas.dk there is a button when clicked goes to .../something/frank.dk but the page doesn't reload. I am trying to run a javascript code on .../something/frank.dk

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("frank") != -1) {
(function () {

    //Check ready state
    function ready() {
        console.info("DOM loaded");
    }

    if (document.readyState === "loading") {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
    } else {

        ready();
    }


// my code goes here

    setTimeout(run, 1000);
    ready();

})();

}
```

The code works fine when I manually reload the page, but how do I get the code to execute when the url changes? 
(I only work with vanilla javascript 'cos we don't use jQuery at my job.)

Comment: Can you make this code available on the next page too?

Comment: by storing it in a separate JS file and include it in .html file of the second page too

Comment: I don't have access to the html due to the setup we have. Even though I look for .../something/frank.dk in the code,  it is like the code executes on .../something/jonas.dk

Comment: Can you investigate the button onClick function handler, it can be that it uses https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState since and doesn't work as a proper link.

Comment: In general you should not have a need to trigger page reloads and it should happen only when the new document (page) actually is loading